# what is the meaning of key size of cipher

Tags: linux, encryption

What is the key size or key length of the cipher ,
And I heard that  128 bit key, 1024 bit RSA key , what does that mean?

for suppose there is a 1024 bit key ,
I thought that 1024 means  number of bits required to store the key , am I right?

and I have my public and private keys ( SSL keys )   , how can I find the key size of my 
certs ( public key and private key). 
Is there any linux tool to find the key size?

Answer (score 1):

All explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size.

To check key size of your cert you can use for example `openssl`:

`openssl x509 -in your_cert_in_pem_format.crt.pem -noout -text`

Comment: If possible Please give the explanation for the key size  in answer instead of pure hyper link.